# Obtain string representation of any file, C++

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to get the representation of any file (I mean `.mp3`, `.mp4`, `.jpg`, `.txt`, ...) in some way that allows me to work with it as if it was a string, saving that representation on a characters' array or on a string itself.

I don't know how this information can be extracted... Maybe in hex code, at byte level or even at bit level. I was looking for something using the `fstream` class, but not necessarily.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look out for [`magic numbers`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? an example may help. thanks.

Comment: I have no any code yet, actually. I'm trying to understand simply how files are really stored at a low level, but in a way that allow us to treat it from a programming language. Then I just want to do several operations with this data for a few files, like length measurement and so.

Comment: Virtually any file access scheme will allow you to read the file as an array of bytes (which in C could be `char[]`, of course), if you have enough RAM.  If you attempt to read an arbitrary file as characters, however, you will inevitably corrupt the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is the wrong thing to use to store binary data.  Consider an `std::vector<unsigned char>` or similar instead.  Then you could write

```
std::ifstream is("myfile.mp3", std::ifstream::binary);

// Find the length of the file
is.seekg(0, is.end);
std::streampos length = is.tellg();
is.seekg(0, is.beg);

// Create a vector to read it into
std::vector<unsigned char> bytes(length);

// Actually read data
is.read((char *)&bytes[0], length);

// Close the file explicitly, since we're finished with it
is.close();
```

The data will end up in `bytes`.  Note here that we're relying on a property of `std::vector`, namely that it allocates a contiguous chunk of memory.  (In C++11, you might prefer to write `bytes.data()` instead of `&bytes[0]`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Actually, I had to make a cast to (char*) on read() function since it is the argument it needs. Besides that, when I try to print that, there are lots of odd characters, so I wonder if the result is correct. For instance, if we get all this characters again and we create a new file, are we going to obtain a correct audio file?

Comment: @user2018219 Don't think of them as characters.  They're bytes (binary values between 0 and 255).  C/C++ just happens to call the byte type `char` instead of `byte`.  If you have a C99 compliant system you could `#include <inttypes.h>` and use `uint8_t` instead (though that is probably just a `typedef` to `unsigned char`).  Anyway, just think of them as numbers and not characters and you'll be fine.  And yes, putting them into a new file will give you a correct audio file.

Comment: @user2018219 As for what the numbers in that vector *should* be, and what they mean, you need to refer to [the MPEG 2 Layer 3 specification](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=26797)

Comment: So, is it correct using chars (or casting) instead of unsigned char? read() function need a char* as first argument. It was not clear for me, sorry. About the characters issue, I tried to think on characters instead of bytes because my intention is to insert new characters that can't be founded in the read document before. I guess it is not possible... Do you know any way? Thank you again, really.

Comment: @user2018219 In my experience, using `char` (which can be either signed or unsigned depending on the compiler) or `signed char` to represent binary data typically leads to bugs.  I’d strongly recommend `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t`) instead.  As for modifying the file you loaded, you can use any of [the methods of `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to do so, but you *must* comply with the specification for the kind of file you have loaded or the result won't be valid.